Как получить число посетителей страниц сата за все время существования метрики?
Коллеги, прошу вас помочь с получением данных о просмотре страницы из ЯД-метрики.
Сама я в JS очень слаба.
Мне надо
САБЖ:

Есть ЯД-счетчик, что собирает данные по сайту.
Есть страницы, с блочком, в которые надо выводить число прочитавших/почитай посетивших эту страницу за все время.
Надо обновлять данные раз в неделю.

ПРОБЛЕМА: Как это организовать?

Надо получить с метрики данные. - вообще не понимаю. АПИ - где и что
смотреть? Какой код писать? Что брать и куда???
Среди них выявить число посещений данной такой-то страницы за все время. - если получу
тело объекта, заберу.
Вывести их в span. - нет проблем.

Я думала получить это через fetch, но пока даже не понимаю какую ссылку ему скормить то?
Потом мне надо установить таймер на то, чтобы еще раз дернуть АПИ. Как это по фен-шую я тоже не пойму.
Прошу, помогите с этим.
Заранее благодарю.
